# Managing a list of URIs to add_filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

ecommerce shop with categories such as tshirts, sweaters etc., I use filter plugin to create seo friendly URLs and dynamic categories, so then tshirt + black attribute become Black T-Shirt page.

However, there are many combinations, like tshirt + black and white filters enabled. This kind of pages I'd like not to index in google. So far I came up with solution as follows, since I use Rank Math plugin for controlling seo, if URL matches, then I update with hook to index, otherwise it's all set to noindex.

I am curious if this approach won't slow down the server and if there isn't a better way to do so? Let's not think for now about difficulties in maintaining

```
add_filter('rank_math/frontend/robots', function($robots) {
    // List of URL fragments to check against
    $noindex_url_fragments = [
        '/shop/filter1',
        '/shop/filter2',
        '/shop/filter3',
        '/shop/filter4'
        // etc - up to 50 URIs
    ];

    foreach ($noindex_url_fragments as $fragment) {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $fragment) !== false) {
            $robots["index"] = 'index';
        }
    }
    return $robots;
});
```